# Number of elements in $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ with bounded $2$-norm

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, estimation, integer-lattices, lattices-in-lie-groups

I wonder if there are good estimate for the number of elements in $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ with $2$-norm bounded by $T$ as $T \to \infty$, namely

$$\#\{g\in SL(d,\mathbb Z):\|g\|_2:=\sqrt{ \sum_{ij}g_{ij}^2} \le T\}.$$

It would be great if there is a sharp estimate for this problem. Any proof (even for the case $d=2$) of reference will be appreciated!

Comment: For $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$, thinking to the $\sup$ norm instead of the $2$-norm, $\sum_{(c,d)=1,|c|< T,|d|< T} T/\min(|c|,|d|)$ may be off by a not too large factor.